# Programmatically create new Schedule Updates Entity Reference on Node

Tags: entities, commerce

I’m attempting to populate an entity referenced field created by the Scheduled Updates module within a content type, Event. Within Event I have two Scheduled Updates fields to check and uncheck the Sticky at top of list option.

I also have a product, Promote Event, in which the user is required to add a Begin Promoting Date, an Entity Reference to an Event, and a Quantity. Once a user purchases the Promote Event, I’d like to populate the Scheduled Updates fields within the Event content type with the data used in the purchase.

I can’t seem to figure out how to programmatically populate the Scheduled Update fields within the Event content type after the purchase of Promote Event.

Within my custom module I have:

```
public function orderCompleteHandler(WorkflowTransitionEvent $event) {
  /** @var \Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderInterface $order */
  $order = $event->getEntity();

  // Order items in the cart.
  $items = $order->getItems();
  if($order->bundle() == 'promoted_event'){    
    $beginPromo = $items[0]->get('field_begin_promotion')->getValue();
    $beginPromo = $beginPromo[0]['value'];
    $quantity = $items[0]->get('quantity')->getValue();
    $quantity = str_replace('.00', '', $quantity[0]['value']);
    $eventId = $items[0]->get('field_event_to_promote')->getValue();
    $eventId = $eventId[0]['target_id'];
    $endPromo = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($beginPromo. ' + '. $quantity .' days'));

    $node = Node::load($eventId);
    // Get the promote_event Entity Reference
    $promoteEvent = $node->get('promote_event')->first();
    // Get unPromoteEvent
    $unPromoteEvent = $node->get('unpromote_event_')->first();
    if($promoteEvent){

    } else {
      $dateTime = new DrupalDateTime($beginPromo, 'UTC');
      $timestamp = $dateTime->getTimestamp();
      $node->promote_event[] = [
        'user_id' => 1,
         'type' => 'node__sticky',
         'update_timestamp' => $timestamp
       ];
       $node->save();
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Hi John and welcome! If I get you right, you want to create a new ScheduledUpdate entity of type Promote Event and set the node->promote_event field to point to the new entity. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes! I believe you are right. It's different than the way I was thinking about it, but yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one example of how to add a ScheduledUpdate to your 'host' entity, in your case a node.

```
$scheduled_update = ScheduledUpdate::create([
  'type' => 'node__sticky',
  'status' => ScheduledUpdateInterface::STATUS_UNRUN,
  'sticky' => NodeInterface::STICKY,
  'update_timestamp' => $timestamp,
  'entity_ids' => [$eventId],
]);
$scheduled_update->save();
$node->promote_event = $scheduled_update->id();
$node->save();
```

Good luck!